# 'request.auth != null' returning no data for any users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Making an app using Flutter.

I'm doing a general test before I continue further with my security settings, but as soon as I set the requirement to be authenticated the app shows nothing despite the two test accounts I have being registered with the app. My security settings appear as such:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
  match /Events {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  
  }

  }
}
```

And the data being stored is Firestore to be accessed appears as:

[image]

These then appear in Cards in a ListView on the app.

Communication between Firebase and the app works as I can see the data being passed back and forth for the Cards.

Users are each assigned a User UID by Firebase so I can't see why this isn't working?

EDIT: Added an image of the error that is displayed:

[image]

EDIT 2: Code that calls on Firebase:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plancel/components/event_card.dart';
import 'package:plancel/components/menu_drawer.dart';
import 'package:plancel/settings.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({super.key});

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  //sign user out method
  void signUserOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //navigate to settings
    void goToSettingsPage() {
      //pop drawer
      Navigator.pop(context);

      //go to new page
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const SettingsPage(),
          ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: const Text(
          'APP NAME',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/eventform');
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
      //TODO remove My Profile
      drawer: MenuDrawer(
        onSettingsTap: goToSettingsPage,
        onSignOut: signUserOut,
      ),
      //
      //main event display
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Events")
            .orderBy("date", descending: false)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final post = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                return EventCard(
                    titleEvent: post['eventTitle'],
                    locationEvent: post['eventLocation'],
                    dateEvent: post['date'],
                    timeHour: post['timeHour'],
                  timeMinute: post['timeMinute'],
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Error${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your code that performs the query?  Does the query yield any errors?  Please edit the question to show the complete code sample and your debugging details. Make sure you are doing error checking, and show that the user is signed in before the query happens by logging their UID.

Comment: So my issue is that they don't appear with these settings. It should show to any authorised user but it doesn't.

When I return the rules to just say 'allow read, write: if true;' it works fine.

Essentially this is my first test before I continue as if this shows nothing then there is an issue somewhere.

Comment: @DougStevenson see EDIT 2 and no errors on the query, all coming through fine. THe reason I am at this point is that so far there have been no other issues and I need to establish the security settings before moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because with the `match /Events` statement you are not specifying a **document** path but a collection path.

You need to specify a document path and use the wildcard syntax for that, since you have several docs in the `Events` collection:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /Events/{docId} { 
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    
  }
}
```

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#basic_readwrite_rules) for more detailed explanations.

Comment: Want to know the worst part? I know this and was blind to it! Just having one of those Mondays I guess. Thank you, Renaud.